# LPTHW Excercise #40- dictionary troubles

Tags: python, function, dictionary, while-loop

I've been struggling with this exercise, and while I understand what the whole program does I can't follow along. Please correct me where I am going wrong: first the dictionary `cities` is created, then New York and Portland are assigned to NY and OR in that dictionary. Then a function is created called `find_city` with parameters `themap` and `state`. The `if` statement in this function confuses me as to exactly how it works.

The first line after the function doesn't seem necessary, but perhaps this is where my knowledge needs to be extended. Why assign `cities['_find']=findcity`? Also, why does the variable `_find` have an underscore before it? I know you can make variables that are strings whatever you want, but it seems pretty arbitrary to just have a random underscore as the first character in this string, perhaps there's a reason?

So then the while loop- the user is asked to input a state, and if it's not `state` the loop breaks. I'm not sure exactly how `state` is defined, since the only place I see it is as one of the parameters of `find_city`.

The line `city_found=cities['_find'](cities,state)` seems to be the equivalent of `city_found=find_city(cities,state)`. The next line prints `city_found`, which seems to be the output of the `find_city` function. I just can't really grasp the process here well enough to create a similar program with dictionaries. Sorry for the long post, I've been stuck here for a while. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
cities = {'CA': 'San Francisco', 'MI': 'Detroit', 'FL': 'Jacksonville'}

cities['NY'] = 'New York' 
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

def find_city(themap, state): 
    if state in themap:
        return themap[state] 
    else:
        return "Not found." 

cities['_find'] = find_city

while True: 
    print "State? (ENTER to quit)", 
    state = raw_input("> ")

    if not state: break

city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state) 
print city_found
```

Comment: In python, an underscore before a name usually denotes an internal function that should not be accessed. In this case, I think the underscore differentiates it from the rest of the entries in the list. This exercise is used to demonstrate what one _can_ do with dicts, not necessarily what one should do. Call the find_city() function is a perfectly legitimate way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see.

find_city itself makes sense:

```
def find_city(themap, state): 
    if state in themap:
        return themap[state] 
    else:
        return "Not found."
```

So I'm not sure what about the if statement you're finding confusing.  If state is a key in themap, it returns the corresponding value; if not ("else"), it returns the string "Not found." instead.

```
cities['_find'] = find_city
```

What this line does is the fun part.  Dictionaries don't need to store just one kind of object as a value (or a key for that matter, although keys have stricter requirements -- in a real dictionary, it doesn't matter if you have a sentence or a picture beside a word, but it's hard to find something if the keywords are changing).  Here, we're storing the *function itself* in the dictionary, to be called later.

The initial prefix underscore is simply a hint to the reader which means "this is internal".  Python doesn't really have private variables like some other languages do, but we do sometimes follow the convention that when something is internal or a little special, we use one leading underscore.

As for where state is defined, that happens here:

```
state = raw_input("> ")
```

which means "read string input from the user and label it by the variable name 'state'".  Note that although this is called state, and the second argument to find_city is called state, they're separate things.

Finally,

```
`city_found=cities['_find'](cities,state)` seems to be the equivalent of `city_found=find_city(cities,state)`.
```

Yep!  You've got it exactly, because cities['_find'] returns the function find_city.   This is a little strange to do -- most people would use a class instead of a dictionary in which functions and data were mixed up -- but it works.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you more- this is extremely helpful! One small question I have is why the while loop breaks only if you press enter, but if you type in a non-state it says Not Found and continues to loop.

Comment: @user1198611: why wouldn't it keep looping?  The only break condition inside the loop (after fixing your indentation issue) is "if not state: break", which since state is a string basically means "if len(state) == 0: break".  If you wanted it to break, you could put in an "if city_found == "Not found.": break condition yourself.

Comment: Ahh ok, so as long as a string of characters is the input, it won't break.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  And welcome to the family of three-letter-named users.  It's like anonymity but not quite. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First, your confusion around the if statement. I think part of your confusion around the if statement is because you copied the program incorrectly. The last two lines in your code should be indented so that they are inside the `while True:` block.

The way it works when properly indented is when you hit enter (without entering any other text) during the `state = raw_input("> ")`, `state` is assigned a value of `""`, or, the empty string. Testing that for truthiness using `bool("")` returns `False`.

An underscore as the first character in Python generally denotes a function that is used internally to the object. Its just a naming convention, Python itself doesn't actually interpret it any differently. In other languages, the `private` keyword would be used instead of this convention. Don't worry too much about the underscore.

The idea of putting the `find_city` function inside the dictionary as a value is probably to teach you that functions in python are considered "First-class citizens", a computer science term meaning that you can store the function itself and pass it around like it were any other object. This means that you could do something like this:

```
def callFirstParamWithOtherParams(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return arg1(arg2, arg3)

callFirstParamWithOtherParams(find_city, cities, state)
```

Comment: Ah you're right! Copy and pasting things into stackoverflow doesn't seem to retain the indents for me, and I must've missed those last two lines. Interesting point about functions, they seem to be objects that actually do more. My understanding is slowly improving, thanks very much for the response.

Comment: No problem. One cool way to improve the above example would be to use the idea of partial function application. Check out this gist for an example of it added to this exercise: https://gist.github.com/93e102af9f988dbba8b3